# How can I tell if an element is being dragged using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

How can I check if an element is being hovered over and/or clicked on and/or dragged? I need this info so I can stop infinite loops for the duration of the drag.

Comment: Lol I figured someone would notice the "and or"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI's Draggables feature.  It allows you to set a callback function for when the drag starts.  Documentation is at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-start.  It also has a callback for during a drag.

You can already set callback functions for hover and click via jQuery's click() and mouseover() events.  http://docs.jquery.com/Events

Comment: There's also a [`jQuery.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method that handles both mouse in and mouse out...